How can I transfer Rigify controller animation to armature bones?
Is there any solution to transfer Rigify animation to the bones. I made animations using Rigify controller but now I want to use that animations in game engine. Is it possible to transfer animation or bake animations to armature?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210074/blender-rigify-character-animation-to-unity-looks-so-weird?rq=1 and CGDive's accompanying tutorial. Also read his first comment below the video about changes in later Blender versions.
